# Python 3.2: File input/output with loops

Tags: python, file, for-loop, file-io, while-loop

How would I do the same thing below using loops to make the program more efficient and not brute force?

I am trying to read values from a file, convert them to float, take the average of the first three numbers, write the average into a new file, and continue for the next three numbers.

Example:

Original file:

```
20.1
18.2
24.3
16.1
45.5
42.3
46.1
43.8
44.4
```

New file:

```
20.87
19.53
28.63
34.63
44.63
44.07
44.77
```

This is my code:

```
def smooth(rawDataFilename, smoothDataFilename):
    aFile = open(rawDataFilename, 'r')
    newFile = open(smoothDataFilename, 'w')

    num1 = float(aFile.readline())
    num2 = float(aFile.readline())
    num3 = float(aFile.readline())
    num4 = float(aFile.readline())

    smooth1 = (num1 + num2 + num3) / 3
    smooth2 = (num2 + num3 + num4) / 4

    newFile.write(str(format(smooth1, '.2f')))
    newFile.write('/n')
    newFile.write(str(format(smooth2, '.2f')))

    aFile.close()
    newFile.close()
```

Comment: What happens, and what doesn't?

Comment: Are you looking for a moving average, or the average of each set of 3? Your question and your numbers say two different things.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve your task with a loop:

```
def smooth(rawDataFilename, smoothDataFilename):
    data = []
    with open(rawDataFilename, 'r') as aFile, open(smoothDataFilename, 'w') as newFile:
        for line in aFile:
            num = float(line)
            data.append(num)
            if len(data) >= 3:
                smooth = sum(data) / len(data)
                newFile.write(format(smooth, '.2f') + '\n')
                del data[0]
```

Differences to your solution:

- `with` takes care for clean closing of files, even on error
- I use a list for collecting the data and smoothing
- I put line breaks between the numbers instead of the sequence `/n`

I suppose you want the moving average as your code indicates and not 3-tuple-wise averages as your text suggests.

Answer (score 0):

If your task is to take the average of each set of three numbers from the line, here is something that does exactly that:

```
from itertools import izip

with open('somefile.txt') as f:
   nums = map(float, f)

with open('results.txt', 'w') as f:
   for i in izip(*[iter(nums)]*3):
      f.write('{0:.2f}\n'.format(sum(i) / len(i)))
```

The `izip` is from the [grouper recipie](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/itertools.html#recipes) from itertools. However, I suspect you need something else based on your actual results. I hope this gets you going.